# Passing a generic list to a multi-parameter method in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, generics

Working on a program where I need to pass three pieces of information to a method that will, in turn, create a row for a table from the data passed in.

The variables are:

```
var runningTally = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
var comments = query.ToList();
var columns = query.ToList();
```

I'd call the method like this:

```
tReport.Rows.Add(row);
foreach (var key in _masterList.Keys)
{
    CreateRow(key, runningTally, columns);
}
```

I was hoping my method signature could look like this:

```
private void CreateRow(string key, IDictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>
 runningTally, List<T> columns)
```

But that doesn't work (the editor complains that the type 'T' can't be found).  I was hoping someone could tell me how to properly use a generic list as a parameter for a method. I appreciate any help and advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to mark the method as generic.

Like this:

```
private void CreateRow<T>(string key, IDictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>
 runningTally, List<T> columns)
```

Notice the method name itself has the generic parameter added to it.

Comment: Can I do that, even though the other parameters are not generic?

Comment: Yep! All that's doing is letting the C# compiler know that somewhere in the parameter list will be a generic type called `T`

Comment: Hey, that worked!  Thanks so much!  As soon as time is up, I'll mark the answer.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: @rossipedia Actually, the generic arguement doesn't even need to be used in the parameters at all.  It could just be in the return type, or even neither.  (While that last option is unusual, it's done on occasion.)